# Export PyCharm project configuration, in a multi-project environment

Tags: pycharm

I'm currently working on a project where we use a python mono-repo, which includes many different projects.

When using Pycharm to configure the working environment, we open the project at the root directory level and then attach each project we need.
After that, we configure each project's dependencies, interpreter (we use `poetry`), and structure "by hand".

This is a very excruciating process since we have many projects and dependencies between them.

I wonder if there's a way to automate it all. Since each project has its own configurations in its `.idea` folder (specifically in the `modules.xml` and in the `module_name.iml` files) which change frequently, I can't store it in our VCS.

My end goal is that when a co-worker clones our repo, he will be able to build the project using Pycharm seamlessly, or at least way more effortlessly than now.